# Relation between mass and energy

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

I understand that the mass-energy relation in $E=mc^2$ means that a stationary body has rest energy,that can be converted into other forms. But why does this energy conversion  have to result in a decrease in the mass of the body in question?

Answer (score 1):

If you use some process to create energy, **E**, then you must have consumed an amount of mass, **M**, such that $$E=Mc^2$$.  This reduces your starting mass by the amount **M**.

If this were not so, then you would be able to create endless energy via your process, in violation of the Principle of Conservation of Energy.

Of course there are other ways to extract energy, such as chemical or mechanical, but your question assumes that mass conversion is part of the process.

Comment: Stored chemical or mechanical energy also results in an increase in the apparent mass of whatever is storing this energy (such as a battery or a chemical molecule i.e. a fully charged battery technically weighs more). However, this usually isn't noticeable as the amount of energy per unit of mass is generally very small compared to $c^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The energy conversion does not decrease total mass, but may transfer it to another system. The mass may or may not still be part of the system, depending on how you defined the system. Say you have a radioactive material. Some binding energy in the nucleons will be released as heat into the surrounding mass of the material. The answer to your question depends on how you define the system. If we take the system to be the nuclei, the mass will decrease. It has been transferred away in the form of heat. If we take the system to be the lump of material, including the heat, the mass has not decreased, as the heat is still contained. You would find the same reading on a precise enough scale if you measured before and after the decay event. If that heat then radiates or conducts away, the “mass” of that energy has left the system. A scale reading at this point would show less mass than before.

Comment: You need to be *much* clearer about what you are saying in the first sentence. Conversion certainly *does* decrease the mass of something. The released energy might still be contained inside some larger system which would accordingly still have the original mass. Fine. But that first sentence is horrifyingly misleading.

Comment: Doesn’t it depend on whether the converted energy is considered part of the final system?

Comment: Energy is conserved globally, mass is not.

Comment: I'm going to rescind my downvote following the edit, but I still feel that this answer is neither clear enough nor particularly enlightening. Of course it matters what system you examine, but conversion *must* reduce the mass of some (sub)system. Secondly, though you are not explicit this answer reads like you are thinking in terms of a treatment of relativity that has "relativistic mass" and this is one of the parts of the theory where the modern treatment is much better and less murky.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between “mass” and “relativistic mass” for a stationary body?

Answer (score 0):

A body can indeed have more energy and hence mass suppose if it has a high gravitational potential energy means that it suppose a block high above the earth’s surface will indeed have *higher* mass. And if suppose that object is brought down to the surface then it will have lower potential energy and hence lower mass. So you see that as the total energy changes, the mass changes as well. It’s a bit like the $E$ in the equation not only incorporates just energy due to rest mass which we will call suppose $m_0c^2$ but also potential energy $E_p$ so the resultant equation looks something like $m=m_0+E_p/c^2$ as we take $E=mc^2$ where m is the final mass. So you can see how the mass can increase or decrease with potential energy.